# How to fetch a Report in protractor

Tags: protractor

I have written a test case in protractor using jasmine framework. My Automated test case is working properly in protractor. Now I want to fetch a report stating about the status of the test case. Please help me in the report fetching as I am new in protractor.

Comment: Ihave given the path for saving the screen shots (Eg: E:\Screenshot folder) in my config file. Now When I am running the test case in protractor. The test is executing correctly without any errors but at the same time the folder mentioned in the config file for saving the screen shots is getting deleted. Please let me know what can be the solution.

Comment: My config file is :  var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
        
 exports.config = 
 {
 directconnect: true,
 capabilities: {'browserName': 'chrome'},
 framework: 'jasmine',
 specs: ['example.js'],
 jasmineNodeOpts: {
 defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000
 },
 onPrepare: function() {
    // Add a screenshot reporter and store screenshots to `/tmp/screenshots`:
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
     baseDirectory: 'F:\Screenshots'
  }));
   }
   }

Comment: Update your question instead of posting comments. Tell us exactly what the problem is, what errors you get, what is the expected output.